# Is it safe to clone Win 10 partition created in OS X Boot camp to a new drive?

Tags: windows-10, macos, partitioning, ssd, boot-camp

I'm using a Mac Pro (2019) with the newest OS X available. I've created a Win 10 partition via Boot camp on the internal SSD. Now I want to transfer this OS to an external SSD. I'm planning to use Macrium Reflect Free to clone Win 10 partition to the new SSD and remove it's old partition.

However, I remember that Boot camp asks to remove any external drives before creating a new Win 10 partition. Doesn't that mean, this Windows installation won't work fine with any other drive?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392227/does-bootcamp-still-result-in-a-hybrid-mbr-gpt-situation for discussion of hybrid MBR/EFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with cloning the Windows partition, is that it has no boot code.
The boot is handled by bootcamp, which is not part of the Windows partition.

The following procedure comes from the article
[How to clone Boot Camp Windows to USB drive as portable Windows?](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/resource/clone-boot-camp-windows-to-usb-drive.html)

- Start Windows from the Boot Camp partition
- Connect the USB drive to the Mac computer.
- Download, install and run
  [Hasleo WinToUSB free version](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/)
- Click "Windows To Go USB"
- For "Select installation source" select "Current Windows OS"
- For "Select destination drive" select the destination drive
- For Partition scheme select the "GPT for UEFI" or "MBR For BIOS and UEFI"
- Click Proceed and acknowledge you wish to format (all data on the
  external disk will be lost)
- For test, restart the Mac and immediately hold down the Option key,
  then select the USB drive and press Return to boot from it.

You will find more information with screenshots in the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to look like a 'product recommendation' which tend to be frowned on here,  but really the only thing that can clone Boot Camp *properly* is [WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/).
[Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) can clone the Windows drive, but it cannot make the partitions on the new drive.

You've never been able to do it from Windows itself, you have to deal with it as a special partition structure, which Windows doesn't see properly from within.